# How to show and change html content at the same time

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4

I have the following hidden bootstrap alert `div` which I setup to show errors

I want to show that and change the html content of it at the same time. I tried the following jquery that will show the `errorDisplay`. But it is not working.

```js
var errorDisplay = $("#errorDisplay").text();
$("#errorDisplay").html(errorDisplay);
$('#errorDisplay').show();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="errorDisplay" style="display:none;">
  <strong>Error!</strong>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code works fine. The only odd thing is that you're setting the `html()` of the element to what it already has, so nothing appears to change

Comment: okay...i do this way `$('#errorDisplay').show();
   $("#errorDisplay").text("some text");`. But the strong tag gone. How to keep the strong tag at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your id to the `<strong>` tag

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert alert-danger" style="display:none;">
  <strong id="errorDisplay">Error!</strong>
</div>
```

No need to get the error text first.

```
$("#errorDisplay").html(errorDisplay);
$('#errorDisplay').show();
```

Alternatively you could leave your id where it is and add `<strong>` tags to your error text

```
$("#errorDisplay").html(`<strong>${errorDisplay}</strong>`);
$('#errorDisplay').show();
```

Note that I am using ES6 backticks for the error text in order to put a variable inside a string

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps:

```
//1. clear the html inside 
$("#errorDisplay").empty();

//2. a append new html inside it:
$("#errorDisplay").append("you updated html here..");

//3. now show the popup:
$('#errorDisplay').show();
```

Comment: jQuery has no `innerHTML()` method.

Comment: let me know if you have any issue now.